# How to combine variable value to k8s field value?

Tags: kubernetes

all

Currently I'm setting the RBAC in the following way:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: system:serviceaccount:default:default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

However I want to include the namespace value for User, I just changed above code into this

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: read-pods
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: system:serviceaccount:$(namespace):default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

and I create the resource in this way `kubectl apply -f k8s -n akka`

```
Forbidden to communicate with Kubernetes API server; check RBAC settings. Response: [{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:akka:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"akka\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

Seems NOT WORKING, so my question is is there anyway to insert the namespace value for the field?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Variable substitution is something Helm can provide. Though Helms use case would normally be on a whole application and not a single configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to update environment variables in k8s manifests is to use envsubst.

Follow the below steps

1. Install envsubst
2. export namespace="my-test"
3. Use the below command to update the variable and deploy the same into k8s cluster

envsubst your-manifest.yaml | kubectl apply -f -